# How to use a not minified version of jQuery in PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, jquery, primefaces

I have a very basic and simple question, but unfortunatelly various google queries have brought me no success...

How to use **development jQuery** version with **PrimeFaces**? I'm getting error somewhere in jQuery engine, but because of the minification it's impossible for me to say what is wrong and post a meaningfull question on any forum...

Comment: An error in jQuery core means in 99% of the cases, that there is an error in YOUR code. Check your code with a debugger which line of your code gets executed right before the js-engine jumps into the jQuery functions.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell. Mind to add your code which might cause the problem together with the error-message?

Comment: But this question is not about this error, but about using non-obfuscated version of jQuery. Without knowing what function has failed it's not easy to set a trap anyway.

Comment: I know what your question is about, but as I already mentioned in my first comment, it is very unlikely that the error REALLY is cause by jQuery but rather by faulty code you wrote. Also the jquery is not obfuscated but only minified, that's a difference. In 99,9% of all cases, debugging your side of the code will solve the problem.

Comment: I wasn't aware that word *obfuscation* is not so widely known. Yes, in jQuery word it is called 'minimization'. But I think that the aim of this question should be obvious anyway.

Comment: It's not a "jquery" thing. Obfuscation and minification are two completely different things. Minification is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code (whitepsaces,comments,newlines,to some extend block delimiters). In a very strict sense, this also includes shortening variable and function names. This makes the sourcecode hard to read, this however is not the original intend. Obfuscation on the other side is not intended to minify the code, but to decrease the readability for the human eye to "protect" code (which is "useless" because it can be reverse engineered)

Comment: Btw. did you succeed with your original problem - get the error out of your code?

Comment: Yes, but only after applying hack from Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download *primefaces-X.X-sources.jar* it contains non minified version of jQuery

Grab it from here :  [Download Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/downloads.html)

Than replace the *META-INF\resources* folder - take the one from the source jar and place it in your original jar ), And when you'll have that client side js error again , a meaningful jQuery source code will be shown...

Comment: Could you expand your answer? I have sources jar and what now?

Comment: Hmm so I should put the sources in WAR or replace the jquery manually?

Comment: yes , You need to replace *Binary* version of jar with the *Source* version in your war (but I'm not so sure that the issue is in jquery sources... try to check your code first or ask a new question with your current issue...)

Comment: This hack is functioning, as long as maven will not overwrite the library, so it's the last resort option...

Comment: its not a hack at all... I'm not a maven user , so you could ask if someone knows about a way to load the sources from maven...

Comment: Sources are uncompiled java files, so you can't run them on server. Java is not a script language.

Comment: I've read, but I've as said, it's a hack only because you'll have to do it on regular base each time maven updates the artifact from central repository.

Comment: Its not a suggestion on how to work on a regular basis, its a solution to your current question on how to find the source of the error in minified jQuery... One should always work with minified js files on a regular basis... but when you want to dive into normal readable code you should *TEMPORARY* replace the minified with non minified

Comment: Yes, one can live with it, but it's not solution I was looking for. Therefore I've upvoted your answer, but not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the non-obfuscated version found on the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/). Make sure you get the same version as the one you're using.

Comment: This works.. but you'll need to extract the jar, replace the file and recompile the jar, which is a pain in itself :(